# Error while running PSTricks

Tags: pdftex

When I am running PSTricks an error is coming like -
File pstrick.sty no found. 
How can I get rid of this and can run my code

Comment: the file is `pstricks` not `pstrick`  fix the typo in your source file and then latex will find the file.

Comment: I have changed that

Comment: Now the error is

Comment: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands

Comment: Remove all auxiliary files generated by the last latex run.

Comment: I dont understand what it means explain me

Comment: is your main file called `pstricks.tex`? don't do that, call it something (anything) else.

Comment: With path as .tex or not

Comment: yes call your file `myfile.tex` or some such, if you call it `pstricks.tex` then your document will load itself instead of loading the real pstricks code  (which is in a file called pstricks.tex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- That is quite possibly the best stab in the dark since [Lord Blackadder's encounter with the young crone.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VByDD_zZbXM)

Answer (score 1):

You mention two unrelated errors.

If you save this file as `pstricks.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstrick}

\begin{document}

zz
\end{document}
```

then you get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pstrick.sty' not found.
```

as there is no `pstrick` package.

If you correct that typo so that the file looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

zz
\end{document}
```

Then you get the error

```
(./pstricks.tex

! LaTeX Error: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 \documentclass{
                   article}
?
```

the problem here is that the pstricks package `pstricks.sty` is just a small latex wrapper that inputs `pstricks.tex` that should be all the core pstricks code but your document is in the input path so as shown by the `(./pstricks.tex` just before the error, so `pstricks.sty` just re-inputs your docuemnt and so you get an error when `\docuemntclass` is seen a second time.

Just rename the file to any other name say `pstricks-test.tex` make sure you delete the existing pstricks.tex then it will run without error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./pstricks-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/home/davidc/texmf/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(./dvips.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.77  <2017/10/04> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
(./pstricks-test.aux) [1] (./pstricks-test.aux) )
Output written on pstricks-test.dvi (1 page, 764 bytes).
Transcript written on pstricks-test.log.
```